# Problem with fieldname having '?'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, boolean

I have a 'user' table with a field name 'process_salary?' which has a boolean datatype

```
@user = User.create(params[:user])
if @user.process_salary? 
 //some code here 
else
 //some code here 
end
```

When I create a new object of user and check for process_salary it gives me following error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `process_salary?' for #<User:0xb6ac2f68>
```

Why does this error occur? Can I avoid it without changing my column name?

When I check it with the debugger it crashes the first time, but after that it runs properly

Answer (score 5):

The question-mark has a special meaning in ActiveRecord. It can be used to check whether a field is true. You are using it as part of your field name which wasn't such a good idea. You could try if @user.process_salary?? exists but I think ultimately it is easiest to change your database column to be called 'process_salary'.

Side note: The 'rails console' is really helpful for playing around with models.

Comment: Ruby doesn't allow `@user.process_salary??` without getting tricky (eg `@user.send(:"process_salary??")`)

Answer (score 1):

As cellcortex posted, question marks at the end of column names are tricky in Rails. If you need to have it there for legacy reasons, you might be able access the attribute as follows:

```
@user['process_salary?']
```

or the more verbose:

```
@user.read_attribute['process_salary?']
```

You can of course test for nil using .nil?.